# Hangfire , EF context used in the Task is not updated, the query inside the task always gives the old values

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, hangfire

The context used inside the Hangfire task , always gives the old database values, it seems like the context is not updating inside the task. How to get the updated info context data inside hangfire task.

calling the task

```
BLL.Extraction NewExtractionCls = new BLL.Extraction();

var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => NewExtractionCls.SearchEngineExtraction("SearchURL", "1","1", null));
```

This is implementation

```
[Authorize]
public void SearchEngineExtraction(string SearchURL, int PageLimit, int SearchEngineID, PerformContext context)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    #region  Main Table - SearchEngineTbl

    var NewExtraction = db.SearchEngineTbls.Where(x => x.SearchEngineID == SearchEngineID).FirstOrDefault();

    var JobID = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
    NewExtraction.JobID = Convert.ToInt32(JobID);
    NewExtraction.SeachEngineURL = SearchURL;
    NewExtraction.Status = "Processing";
    db.SaveChanges();


    var LinkCollectionRefined = ExtractLinkFromThisPage(i, SearchURL, wc).Distinct().ToList();//.Skip(10); 

    foreach (var Link in LinkCollectionRefined)
    {
        using (Entities dbRefreshed = new Entities())
        {
  // I get the same old value here, even if I update the table manually, when I rerun, everything is fine.
            var CurrentStatusOfExtraction = db.SearchEngineTbls.Where(x => x.SearchEngineID == NewExtraction.SearchEngineID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (CurrentStatusOfExtraction.IsActive == false)
            {
                return;
            }

        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You passed `null` to `SearchEngineExtraction`. How `context` can be not null inside this method?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov It is internal implementation I think, it has the job details when the function is called.

Comment: Investigating it could resolve the problem, I guess. For now this code should fail with NRE.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov the code works perfectly , only the db context values is not updated , remains same all through the solution, I had to use dapper to get the latest data.

Comment: Could you show how do you pass `db` variable in the job? I just can't find where it is consructed or passed in the example.

Comment: @ArunPrasadES Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue where EF context is returning old data.